# Prompting a custom context menu whenever a node is left-clicked

Tags: angular, svg, cytoscape.js

I would like prompt a radial context menu surrounding a specific node which has been left-clicked. 
The context menu is created by using `<svg></svg>` and other related HTML tags. 
The context menu consists of multiple elements all of which creates a circle surrounding the clicked node.
Some elements also prompt a branch menu whenever they are hovered.

The example context menu can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaypvu)

The context menu should be seen after every node is clicked like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbdsi.png)

I thought of trying to encode the svg via `encodeURI()` and set the result as the `background-image`of the node but as seen above the context menu includes CSS, binded event: `mousehover` and directive: `ngIf`. Therefore the context menu is not just a simple image.

The context menu should be seen within `<canvas></canvas>` created by cytoscape.js. I also tried to show the context menu on top of the canvas however I failed to align the svg properly appearing on the clicked node.

I wonder if there is any workaround to this problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu ?

Comment: I did. However the API does not let me do the modifications on the context menu in order to display an inner branch menu whenever a command is hovered as shown in the example in my question. Therefore I needed to code my own context menu.

Comment: I thought the cxtmenu had a content and css property for this kind of requirenment? Can you please post the cxtmenu approach additionaly? Thx

Comment: @StephanT. Yes CSS and event binding is required for my specific use case. Actually I initially wanted to modify https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu to attach custom events to its selections by hovering on them. Not by clicking. But I didn't succeed on changing any core functionality of it. Therefore I wrote my own cxtmenu which can be totally seen here -->https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaypvu I want to propmt my custom cxt menu to be prompted on nodes like cytoscape.js/cxtmenu